# Phonegap NativeAudio will not play on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use this plugin with my PhoneGap Build app:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

I call it in my **config.xml**

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativeaudio" source="npm" />
```

Then in my **onDeviceReady** I load the sound like so:

```
if( window.plugins && window.plugins.NativeAudio ) {

    window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadSimple( 'slide', 'sounds/slide.mp3', function(msg){
    }, function(msg){
       alert( 'error: ' + msg );
    });
}
else {
   alert("load failed");
}
```

and then in my function that happens every time a move a is made I put

```
window.plugins.NativeAudio.play( 'slide' );
```

Then I package and build the app and install on my phone via TestFlight

The sound is stored in my `www/sounds/` folder, if I change the path/filename in the loading code my phone will alert "load failed", but with the correct path it remains silent implying a success. And yet it plays no sounds when called.

I have tried to play the same sound via the Media plugin and it worked so I know there is nothing wrong with the .mp3 itself, but it was being called to many times for Media to handle freezing up the app.

EDIT: Will accept suitable alternatives if this plugin is broken or outdated.

Comment: what is the length and size of your audio file ?

Comment: The file is on 7kb and shows as 0:00 in the file explorer (perhaps that's an issue as well) because it's so short so I doubt it's too complex.

Comment: as i have suggested in Answer, try using preloadComplex . if it not works ,change your Audio file and try again for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the plugin and it works just fine.

You can try their [sample project](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio/tree/master/test)

At first I tried with your code and a sound I downloaded from internet and I was getting this error when trying to play it:
`WARNING:  [0x1f197000] 998: Failure to setup sound, err = -50` (Got success callback on the preload, and this was displayed on the Xcode debug area when calling play)

And the problem was that the sound was to complex to be played with `preloadSimple`, using `preloadComplex` fixed the issue for me, so maybe your sounds are too complex to be played with `preloadSimple`

Note: when using `preloadComplex` you have to pass three params before the success callback,  volume, voices, delay, should be something like:

`window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex( 'slide', 'sounds/slide.mp3', 1, 1, 0, 
    function(msg){
        window.plugins.NativeAudio.play( 'slide' );
    }, function(msg){
       alert( 'error: ' + msg );
    });`

Comment: Ok, it makes little sense to me as my sound file is a small less than once second sound of only 7kb, but changing it from simple to complex seems to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: yeah, sounds strange. The audio files on the sample project are 19-34KB for simple sounds and 1.4MB for the complex background sound. Maybe it's something related to the bit rate or frequency of the file. You can use a tool such as MediaInfo to check your file https://mediaarea.net/es/MediaInfo

Comment: Yeah I will try different sounds and stuff to try to figure it out and see if I can narrow down the issue. It was just delaying the release of my game so I just needed something to work. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

> may be the issue is with the size/type of your audio file so use **preloadComplex** insted of **preloadSimple**

```
 preloadComplex: function ( id, assetPath, volume, voices, delay, successCallback, errorCallback)
```